# Ubuntu14.04 can not install g++

Tags: apt, g++

My computer environment: Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit OS;
gcc version:
**gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)**

I tried to install g++ by executing:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Then I got this output information:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 g++ : Depends: g++-4.8 (>= 4.8.2-5~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install -f` help?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy g++ g++-4.8`

Comment: sudo apt-get install -f  is not wok!!       And,  sudo aptitude install g++   is not work, too.

Comment: :~$ apt-cache policy g++ g++-4.8
g++:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6
  Version table:
     4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 0
        500 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
g++-4.8:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.8.2-19ubuntu1
  Version table:
     4.8.2-19ubuntu1 0
        500 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

Comment: You have to enable `trusty-updates` in *Software & Updates*

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable `trusty-updates`. Open <kbd>Software & Updates</kbd> and set a thick for `trusty-updates` in the tab <kbd>Updates</kbd>

[image]

After that

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall g++
```